# Is it acceptable for university to ask for detailed financial report?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm applying for a university in the USA and one of the section requires to enter up to five previous employees, their contacts, start/end dates, hours per week, and salary. I mean, that some of the previous aspects are considered personal in Europe.

Is it acceptable for university to ask for financial data and should one provide full, candid answers?

Comment: "Up to five" would include the option of zero.

Comment: Are you applying for admission to a graduate program or for a job (e.g. a post-doc, visiting professor, or tenure track position?)

Comment: @BrianBorchers no, for graduate degree studies.

Comment: Outside of business schools, this is very unusual in my experience.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes, the school I'm applying to offers technical education only.

Comment: As far as I know this is quite normal, also in Europe.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say those details are a bit *too detailed* for comfort, especially for a graduate admission programme. However, the technical rationale behind could be that they might have some consideration for scholarships based on the financial details you provide. In the end, it is your decision.

If you are still concerned about the necessity of those details, you may request the respective department of the University for a clarification of the reason behind them.